# UILongPressGestureReconizer Tag? - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I'm setting up a LPGR like so and I was wonder if I can create a tag in each LPGR. I need to do this so I know which of all my buttons is being pressed...

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressHandler:)];
longpressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 2;
[longpressGesture setDelegate:self];
[pushButton addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];
```

And my method below...

```
- (void)longPressHandler:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
NSLog(@"longPressHandler");
}
```

I know you can't pass arguments via selectors, so I was wondering if I could assign a tag to the LPGR or if in the method I could grab the tag of the button that was using the LPGR? Is any of this possible>?

EDIT:

```
NSInteger *tag = [gestureRecognizer.view.tag];
NSLog(@"%@ longPressHandler",tag);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIGestureRecognizer` has a property `view` which is the view the gesture recognizer is attached to.

Therefore, in your handler method, `gestureRecognizer.view` is the button that the LPGR is attached to and `gestureRecognizer.view.tag` is the button's tag.

**ADDED:** 
Sample code:

```
- (void)longPressHandler:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"longPressHandler");
    NSInteger tag = gestureRecognizer.view.tag;
    NSLog(@"%d longPressHandler",tag);
}
```

Comment: There are several syntax errors in your code: `tag` is a property, therefore no square brackets, `NSInteger` is a scalar type and not an object. I have added the correct code to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a subclass of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and add a `tag` property to it. You could also use [associated objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html) to add the property with a category.